# I am considering quitting piano. Should I do it?

Tags: piano

A month ago, I started to take piano classes. But I am now considering to give up.

Why to play an instrument? I like to listen to music. Why not just listen to them, instead of playing them?

The online classes are boring. I feel like they are slow, and I am all the time doing rhythmic reading with my voice. I don't like the material either, and I feel like I am wasting money to sing and play boring compositions, with dissonances.

I was learning violin, but switched to piano because of the presence of both harmony and melody. But I don't know whether my choice was well done, because I prefer other instruments sounds. Yet, the musics are "dirty" with only melody.

Comment: I don't think anybody but yourself can answer that question.

Comment: You've tried one scheme of online lessons? Try another. If you want harmony as well, there's always guitar. An awful lot of folk teach themselves.

Comment: When I first started learning guitar, I played for maybe a month and then quit for several months because it seemed impossible to even make a simple chord and I felt like I would never be able to get fast enough to play anything even remotely resembling music. After taking that time off, I decided to give it another go and over 20 years later, I'm still playing and I'm glad I went back to it because I can't imagine not playing. My primary instrument is drums, but I love playing both. Maybe you could take a little time off and see how you feel about it after taking a break.

Comment: @Tekkerue - I kinda have the opposite impression with guitar - trying to even hold and play one (let alone a bass) was an instant turn-off for me, to the point that I'd rather learn ukulele because it's smaller.

Comment: @Dekkadeci That's how guitar was for me at first as well. It was so difficult and I was so slow at forming chords, getting all my fingers in the right place, keeping notes from buzzing, not accidentally touching other strings and muting them, etc it was a turn off for me too and that's why I quit after about a month of playing. At that time I thought I was done for good. But after several months I decided to give it another shot and I stuck with it. Ukulele is fun too, it's very similar to guitar (if you capo a guitar at 5th fret and play the four high strings, it's the same tuning as a uke).

Answer (score 1):

I will express my own perspective here, but the choice is yours to make, not mine. learning to play any instrument is usually considered tedious by most people and it seems to take longer than it should to achieve the skills we need to perform well. I compare it to when I first learned to read in school. The reading material was very basic and boring and I could have easily put the books down and never learned to read, but instead I was encouraged by my parents and teachers and I learned to read. That enables me to be able to read and understand instructions, theory, adventures, mysteries, and all sorts of materials that I find entertaining and useful. My learning to play music, guitar, piano, harmonica, and voice, all started out with me learning the basic boring stuff beginners have to suffer through, but I was able to eventually get good enough to play along with others and that was where the fun began for me. Listening is a nice experience, but playing by myself and with others is something I always look forward to. And I usually grab an instrument to play along while I listen to the stereo. In the beginning, learning to play involves work, but somewhere along the way it turns into play.